# unity. физический объект проходит через стену

Tags: unity3d

наверно подход не правильный со сменой позиции физ-объекта персонажа при помощи transform... 
есть физ. объекты-враги, есть физ. объект-персонаж, есть стены, тоже(пока, может не надо) с rigidbody, у всех коллайдеры, на персонаже в rigidbody заблочены Rigidbody ->Constraints ->Freeze по всем позициям и вращениям(иначе враги начинают его крутить-вертеть, а я хочу зафиксировать смещение персонажа по любой из осей при взаимодействии с врагами), персонаж перемещается не Rigidbody.AddForce, а через translate:

```
velocity.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    velocity.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    velocity *= maxSpeed;
    Vector3 translation = velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(translation, Space.World);
    transform.LookAt(transform.position + velocity);
    orientation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
```

результат: персонаж проходит через стены

цель - исключить проход персонажа через стены

Comment: Лучше физику юзай. Проще будет.

Answer (score 0):

"Статичный коллайдер (Static Collider)
Это игровой объект, у которого есть коллайдер, но нету Rigidbody. Статичные коллайдеры используются для геометрии уровней, которая всегда стоит на месте и совсем не двигается. Встречные Rigidbody объекты будут врезаться в статичный коллайдер, но его не сдвинут."  https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Уберите Rigidbody со стен, но оставьте коллайдер, тогда персонаж с коллайдером не будет проходить сквозь стены. Также для статических объектов (для оптимизации, например, освещения) в инспекторе в правом верхнем углу ставим галочку static. https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/StaticObjects.html

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогало то что я использовать данный код в fixedUpdate и с добавлением
того что скорость умножаем на Time.DeltaTime.
Таким образом у тебя столкновение будет проходить момент обработки физики.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]